# How to resolve "ValueError: I/O operation on closed file" error in python which is showing while creating new file and write into it

Tags: python, csv

```
import csv

fileno = 1

record_per_file = 5

lineno = 1

with open('C:/Users/contacts.txt', "r") as csv_file:
    csv_reader = csv.reader(csv_file, delimiter='|')

    with open('C:/Users/contactsextracted' + str(fileno) + '.csv', "w", newline='') as new_file:
        csv_writer = csv.writer(new_file)

        for line in csv_reader:
            if lineno%record_per_file == 0:
                fileno += 1
                lineno += 1
                with open('C:/Users/contactsextracted' + str(fileno) + '.csv',"w", newline='') as new_file:
                    csv_writer = csv.writer(new_file)
            else:
                csv_writer.writerow(line)
                lineno += 1
```

Comment: Can you mention what line throws the error, would ease the debugging as you dealing with multiple files

Comment: "csv_writer.writerow(line)" when its trying to write the content after 5th repetition

Answer (score 0):

When you create a CSV writer `csv_writer = csv.writer(new_file)`, `new_file` must refer to a file handler that is open.

On lines 19 - 20 you have
    with open('C:/Users/contactsextracted' + str(fileno) + '.csv', "w", newline='') as new_file:
        csv_writer = csv.writer(new_file)

After these 2 lines are over, `new_file` is closed (because the `with` block is over), and the `csv_writer` can no longer be used. When you do try to use it on line 22 `csv_writer.writerow(line)` you get an error.

Now you may see everything work for some time, because you used the exact same name for your variables on lines 12 - 13. And this `csv_writer` does stay open and will work for some time, until the `csv_writer` variable gets overwritten by the new `csv_writer` that you create on line 19, and then subsequently close.

What you want to do is put the code that writes to the CSV writer, inside of a CSV writer `with` context, like so.

```
for line in csv_reader:
    if lineno % record_per_file == 0:
        fileno += 1
        lineno += 1
    else:
        with open('C:/Users/contactsextracted' + str(fileno) + '.csv', "w", newline='') as new_file:
            csv_writer = csv.writer(new_file)
            csv_writer.writerow(line)
            lineno += 1
```

I'm not entirely sure what you're trying to do, but this should get you past the error that you where facing. You might also want to look into using [csv_writer.writerows](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html#csv.csvwriter.writerows) after your for loop has finished instead of using csv_writer.writerow.

Comment: Thanks a lot.  But what is the solution to this? Is there any way I can fix this?

Comment: I've edited my answer to include a solution to the problem.